# cant echo javascript alert from php

Tags: javascript, php

I've looked for an answer already, but I understand how to achieve an alert from php I just don't know what I am doing wrong on this particular piece of code.
I had this working until I added the if statement.

```
if ($errors) {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
        echo "alert('Records Were Uploaded');";
        echo "window.location.href = 'EmployeePicker.php';";
        echo "</script>";
    } else {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
        echo "alert('There was a problem with your file');";
        echo "window.location.href = 'csvUpload.php';";
        echo "</script>";
    }
```

It worked fine when it was just .

```
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
        echo "alert('Records Were Uploaded');";
        echo "window.location.href = 'EmployeePicker.php';";
        echo "</script>";
```

If comment everything out and just do

```
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
        echo "alert('There was a problem with your file');";
        echo "window.location.href = 'csvUpload.php';";
        echo "</script>";
```

this will not work. I'm so confused. It doesn't make sense why the second alert doesn't work.

I forgot to mention, In the if statement from above the first alert will work, it's that second alert that I can't get to fire.

Sorry about the confusion, the $error is a bool. If it is true a filw was uploaded, if false it wasn't.

Comment: Check your Javascript console for errors.

Comment: I tried your code, it worked fine. The problem is elsewhere, or you haven't copied it correctly.

Comment: I agree with @Barmar your code runs fine for me. Other than the ambiguous nature of your `$errors` variable (if true--indicating there /are/ errors--it will take you to the page saying things are okay), everything works fine. Perhaps you can show how the `$errors` variable is set?

Comment: you may need to post your php code too...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing the opposite of what you want:
Your if case doesn't match the action performed inside.
Maybe you should do:

```
if (!$errors) {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
        echo "alert('Records Were Uploaded');";
        echo "window.location.href = 'EmployeePicker.php';";
        echo "</script>";
    } else {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
        echo "alert('There was a problem with your file');";
        echo "window.location.href = 'csvUpload.php';";
        echo "</script>";
    }
```

and you can also save up on `echo` words - and make it more readable - doing sth like:

```
echo <<<HTML
<script type='text/javascript'>
    alert('Records Were Uploaded');
    window.location.href = 'EmployeePicker.php';
</script>
HTML;
```

just if you want :)

---

[EDIT] Note that according to what `$errors` hold (either integer or array), you can check that there is no error by either `!$errors` if integer or `!count($errors)` if array.

---

[EDIT] Trying your second piece of code as a standalone

If you need to trace what is wrong you need to isolate bit by bit!
first try `code 1` as a new php file if it does not alert and redirect on your system then something is wrong in your configs.
If it works something is wrong in your code logic.
I could also run `code 2` with no pb by first setting the `$errors` var to 1 or 0.

**code 1**

```
<?php
$errors = 1;

    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
    echo "alert('There was a problem with your file');";
    echo "window.location.href = 'csvUpload.php';";
    echo "</script>";

?>
```

**code 2**

```
<?php
$errors = 1;
if ($errors) {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
        echo "alert('Records Were Uploaded');";
        // echo "window.location.href = 'EmployeePicker.php';";
        echo "</script>";
    } else {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
        echo "alert('There was a problem with your file');";
        // echo "window.location.href = 'csvUpload.php';";
        echo "</script>";
    }
?>
```

And about your `$errors` var, if true means no error you should definitely rename it to sth less tricky like `$uploadSuccessful`. ;)

Comment: Yes, he has the `if` backwards. But the question says that the second block of echoes fails when he takes out the `if` entirely. So there's a different problem.

Comment: @Barmar, the question got edited since we answered. the answer may not be accurate now. I will check later :)

Comment: The edit is just the line that starts with "Sorry". Not any of the code.

Answer (score 0):

It should echo out good. Try checking your php error log file to see if there are any clues as to the issue in there.

Just a small most like likely personal preference of mine that may help you is to separate out the logic a bit.  Please see below.

```
<?php

// STATUS
$errors = true;

// OUTPUTS
$upload_success = "<script type='text/javascript'>";
    $upload_success .= "alert('Records Were Uploaded');";
    $upload_success .= "window.location.href = 'EmployeePicker.php';";
$upload_success .= "</script>";

$upload_fail = "<script type='text/javascript'>";
    $upload_fail .= "alert('There was a problem with your file');";
    $upload_fail .= "window.location.href = 'csvUpload.php';";
$upload_fail .= "</script>";

//LOGIC
if ($errors) {
    echo $upload_success;
} else {
    echo $upload_fail;
}

?>
```